# how does css for responsive video work

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Looking for ways to make a youtube video on my website responsive, I found this piece of code which works fine:

```
.flex-video {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 67.5%;
  height: 0;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.flex-video.widescreen { padding-bottom: 57.25%; }
.flex-video.vimeo { padding-top: 0; }

.flex-video iframe,
.flex-video object,
.flex-video embed {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

However, I cannot understand how it works. I know that by making the iframe class absolutely positioned and having 100% width and height, it takes all the space that the container provides. But what about the container itself?  What does that 25px padding-top do? And where does that 67.5% padding bottom come from? Since having padding in percent means what percent of the container, how does this css work well on all container sizes?

Can I use different numbers that suit my video better? If yes, how?

Thanks.

Comment: Why is this tagged with `twitter-bootstrap-3`? This isn't Bootstrap-related.

Answer (score 1):

- video has `position:absolute` with `overflow:hidden` - that crops out any extra content other than video
- `padding-top` is used to keep the video seekbar visible without the need to set a fixed height value to the container (value depends on which video player you use)
- `padding-bottom` adds spacing to the video container and is is calculated out of the aspect ratio of the video. If the video is using a 16:9 aspect ratio this means:
  `16.....100%
      x
  9 ...... ?
  9 * 100 / 16 = 56,25%`

The video container height is `56.25%` of the video container width. Depending on your aspect ratio and which player you are embeding you will need to adjust the padding to fit your video.

Comment: For anyone that stumbles here. Padding-bottom is relative to the width not the height, so `padding-bottom: 56.25%;` forces a 16/9 ratio.